# Proving that the sum of two subspaces is a direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem in question is: Suppose U = {(x, y, x + y, x - y, 2x) $\in$ $F^5$ : x,y $\in$ F}. Find a subspace W of $F^5$ such that $F^5$ $=$ U $\oplus$ W.

So far, I've come up with the subspace W $=$ {(0, 0, x, y, z) $\in$ $F^5$ : x,y,z $\in$ F}.

To solve this problem completely with the specified W, I assume that I would have to prove that W is a subspace, show that the sum of U and W is $F^5$, and prove that the intersection of U and W only contains the zero vector.

How would I prove or show that the sum of U and W is $F^5$ and that the intersection only contains the zero vector?

Comment: Hint: Once you show the intersection is zero (see @olgchar's answer), you can just count dimensions to show $U+W=F^5$.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first part (showing that $U+W=F^5$), notice that for any $(a,b,c,d,e)\in F^5$:
$$
\big(a,b,c,d,e\big)=\big(a,b,a+b,a-b,2a\big)+\big(0,0,c-(a+b),d-(a-b),e-2a\big)
$$
Regarding the second part (proving they have an empty intersection), notice that if: 
$$
\vec{v}=(a,b,c,d,e)\in U\cap W
$$
then $a=b=0$ (since $\vec{v}\in W$) and $c=a+b=0$, $d=a-b=0$, $e=2a=0$ (since $\vec{v}\in U$), thus:
$$
\vec{v}=(a,b,c,d,e)=(0,0,0,0,0)=\mathbf{0}\in F^5
$$Can you fill in the details?